# Trying to convert certain formats into a date format

Tags: excel, vba, date-format

I have been able to get the code below to successfully convert general values "19082015" and "9052015" into the date format dd/mm/yyyy.

But when I try converting the general value "19.08.2015" in the same code, it does not run the macro and shows:

Run time error '13':
Type mis-match

On the line "l = Range("A1").Value"

What needs to be done so that it will process "19.08.2015" format also?

```
Sub convertdate()

Dim l As Long
Dim testdate As String
Dim convertdate As Date

l = Range("A1").Value

testdate = CStr(l)

dotdate = False
If InStr(testdate, ".") Then dotdate = True
If dotdate = False Then convertdate = DateValue(CInt(Left(testdate, Len(testdate) - 6)) & "/" & CInt(Mid(testdate, Len(testdate) - 5, 2)) & "/" & CInt(Right(testdate, 4)))
If dotdate = True Then convertdate = DateValue(CInt(Left(testdate, Len(testdate) - 8)) & "/" & CInt(Mid(testdate, Len(testdate) - 6, 2)) & "/" & CInt(Right(testdate, 4)))

Range("A2").Value = convertdate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will be if `Range("A1")` is not a number. So if it does have `.` in it then you cannot put that value into a long. declare `l` as `string` not a `long` and your code will work

Comment: Not quite sure how I missed that! Thank you, works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a2] = CDate(Join(Split([a1], "."), "-"))
```